# Mod_rewrite without {%Document_Root}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used to point all my domains to my web-spaces root. And use an htaccess file like this to point the different domains into different folders

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new.vea.?re.?[net|de]?(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/veare/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/veare/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ veare/$1 [L]
# rewrite parameters that are neither files nor folders
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new.vea.?re.?[net|de]?(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ veare/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My problem now is, that my new web provider does not set the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` so this script doesn't work. Is there any workaround?

So its like this.

**www.test.com/css/style.css**
1. Domain points to `root`.
2. If `root/test.com/css/style.css` exists, it needs to just grab this file, aka redirect into the subfolder `test.com`
3. If it is neither a file, nor a folder, it should just point to the index.php in the subfolder `root/test.com/index.php`

How can i solve it WITHOUT `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`?

Comment: `new web provider does not set the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` - I don't think there is any choice to NOT to set it. It should be always available. To test that create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: Hey, according to the provider it does work, however I found the solution now. Thanks.

Comment: There was no need to hardcode the path even `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` would work.

Comment: Naa, it does not, as I said before, the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` somehow does not work and a statement of the provider confirms, that it will not point to the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

easy fix, use the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` which should indeed tell you the real document root. eg. `customer/123445_12345`. Now you can just use this in your htaccess. Note, that I also had to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to get the full path, like `/css/app.css`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteCond /customer/123445_12345/test/public/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond /customer/123445_12345/test/public/%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /formandsystem/cms/test/index.php?/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond /customer/123445_12345/test/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond /customer/123445_12345/test/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/public/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```